# Web audio getUserMedia is silent in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I am using the Audio API for a project, and noticed recently that it no longer works in Chrome. I've thoroughly checked my code, but it seems ok, since it works fine in Firefox. I noticed that other apps online also have the same problem. You can see it for example here:

http://webaudioplayground.appspot.com/

If you choose live input (it uses your microphone), and connect an analyser, it should have bars that visualize the sound, but on chrome it stays blank.

Does anyone know if this is a problem with Chrome? Or maybe with my system (MacBook Pro, El Capitan). If you are on a different OS, can you check if it works on Chrome and let me know in the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that getUserMedia was recategorized as a "powerful feature" - i.e., it's only available under HTTPS (or localhost).  So https://webaudioplayground.appspot.com/ works fine, but http://webaudioplayground.appspot.com/ will not.  (I'll update the config for webaudioplayground.appspot.com to force HTTPS, but not today.)

Comment: Would be nice if Chrome gave some warning about that. But nope, just silence, nothing but silence (literally).

Comment: Aha, another issue: I've configured some proxies recently, and that explains why my localhost didn't work anymore. If I bypass localhost in my proxies, my localhost does use the microphone in chrome again.